# Vapor barrier for cantilevered kitchen idea

Tags: insulation, subfloor, basement-insulation

*Hi*, all!
So I have this weird kitchen sitch, where it's cantilevered, and the back roughly 2-3 feet are hanging outside of the house. It's a dumb design, but what're ya gonna do?!
I had to have mold remediation done, and I am now missing most of the insulation and drywall on the outer wall. I'm going to rip the rest of it out and replace it with R23 Rockwool + 6 mil vapor barrier and basically redo that wall. Thing is, apparently there was a pretty bad rodent problem (that prior owners didn't address, just like the mold). All the insulation underneath the floor of the cantilever ended up chewed up, a lot of it also affected by whatever leak(s) from the kitchen. I pulled all of that out too. Turns out some of it wasn't even all the way to the end, the fiberglass having rolled up on itself when the original construction was placing it!

I would like to use R30 2x8 Rockwool in those cavities now. It is not faced. That means I need to run a vapor barrier underneath. I could try to carefully stick sheets of plastic inside each cavity perhaps. However, the subfloor OSB is the exact depth of the cantilever. If I pulled that up, I could actually run 6 mil underneath, place the subfloor back down, and then overlap this vapor barrier with the outer wall.

Am I missing anything in this plan?

Also, when placing the OSB back down, should I use some kind of caulk between the plastic and joists, or between subfloor and plastic? What kind would that be? I have a bunch of tubes of acoustic caulk I could smother all over everything.

Thanks!

Some pictures:
Wall view:
[image: Kitchen]

Basement view:
[image: Bays in the basement]

View inside the cantilevered bays I am trying to insulate:
[image: Bay]

Comment: You say it's cantilevered—do you have pics from the underside of the cantilever?

Comment: I haven't been under there, to be honest. I've been meaning to (perhaps the rodent situation would become obvious), but I've been procrastinating because it's a bit nasty, having never been cleaned out of anything. Might rake it out first. I'll try to climb under and get some photos soon. Anything in particular I should look for?

Comment: I dunno...anything that would make insulation get "nasty" too?

Comment: Is that the vapor barrier that I see on the inside of your wall? It sounded like you intend to put your floor cavity vapor barrier on the outside, whereas it looks like the wall's vapor barrier is inside. Is that accurate?

Comment: That's just left-over plastic from when I had mold remediation done, and they covered it up, so the studs weren't exposed. Once I insulate this wall though, the vapor barrier will still be on the inside because New York. I wonder how valid inside/outside is now with hotter summers. Anyway, the cantilever vapor barrier I still want to be on the "inside", immediately under the OSB, as opposed on the outside, bottom of the bays. Either way, I've run into a conundrum with this pulling-up OSB idea: it's not really viable given the majority of the span is covered in floor I don't want to pull up

Comment: I did look under the cantilever the other day, from the outside, and could not find anything interesting, unfortunately. An obvious problem would have been almost better, since easily identifiable problems usually have solutions!

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the subfloor up and place one sheet of plastic that way, that would be best. Acoustic sealant is a good choice for sealing things that need to be sealed, such as overlaps at joints, but is probably overkill (unless you just want to use it up) for screws or nails through the floor and VB into the joist, since the screw or nail will fill the hole it makes.

Comment: Thanks. OK, that sounds good. It sounds like I could probably just run a thin bead of it down each joist before placing the plastic down. That might work well.

But yeah, I bought a 6-pack of the acoustic caulk and I feel like I might as well use it. Never used the stuff before, but been watching a bunch of "RenoVIsion DIY" on YouTube, and that's what he uses to glue a lot of seams around the vapor barrier.

Comment: @Zoinks   You also need to make sure enough fresh air enters the house if you start to seal everything up tight.

Comment: Like a proper air makeup system you mean? I don't have that right now. Fwiw, I'm not plugging up much here. The only real change is that I'd be going from faced insulation in the basement bays to having a sheet of plastic over unfaced